# Statistical Analysis of Multiple Paired Preference Tests

Tags: statistical-significance, paired-data, bradley-terry-model

I have four different methods 'A', 'B', 'C' and 'D' for generating synthetic videos, and I have crowdsourced 6 paired preference tests, one for each combination, where respondents were presented with many pairs of videos and were asked for each pair, which video is the most realistic. The choices included a "no preference" option.

I want now to do a statistical analysis of the data.

**A** One way to analyze the data is to do a statistical test for each of the 6 paired preference tests. What I have found from research regarding paired preference with ties ("no preference") is the following:

1. I could throw out the ties and do a simple binomial test but I think that would not be correct.
2. I can equally divide the ties between the two methods of each test, and then do a binomial test. I have found that this method is more conservative.
3. I can do a paired t-test with each pair having 1 for the winning method  and 0 for the losing method.
4. I can calculate confidence intervals for each of the three choices. However, in this case, if the CI for methods A and B do not overlap, but A (the winning method) overlaps with the "no preference" option (or even more, if "no preference" is the highest), is it right to say that A is significantly better than B ?

I guess there are more methods I can do (Z tests ?) - which one is the most "correct"?

**B** Another way to analyze the tests would be with with a bradley terry model that accounts for ties. In this case, is there any way to evaluate the confidence of the result ? For example if the BT model gives us:

Method A: 33%, Method B: 28%, Method C: 23%, Method D: 18%

are there any "confidence intervals" or another method that indicates how "good" the result is ?